# How to show the step2 div when the user click in "go to step 2"?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a multi step form using bootstrap and jQuery. The multi step form is for a user to buy a product. There are 4 steps: - Step 1 is for the user insert his info (name, email, etc) - Step 2 the user select the payment method - Step 3 the user introduces the payment data - Step 4 present an invoice for the user.

When the user click "go to step 2" the url changes to "store.test/product/5/a-5/payment/paymentMethods" and the user remains in the same payment page, but how to change from step 1 to step 2 in the multi step form?

The step1 html is like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <h6>User Info</h6>
    <form method="post" action="{{route('products.storeUserInfo', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])}}">
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
        </div>
        <!-- other form fields -->
        <input type="submit" href="#step2"
                class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

In paymentcontroller I have the storeUserInfo to collect the user data introduced in step1 and redirect to the same page (My doubt is how to redirect to the same page but show the step2 div):

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        //dd($request);
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ]);
        Session::put('name' ,  $request->name);
        Session::put('surname' ,  $request->surname);
        Session::put('email' ,  $request->email);
        return redirect(route('products.presentPaymentMethods',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }

    public function presentPaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
        $productQuantities =  Session::get('productQuantities');
        return view('products.registration',
            ['productQuantities' => $productQuantities, 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/storeUserInfo', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeUserInfo',
    'as'   =>'products.storeUserInfo'
]);

Route::get('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/paymentMethods', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@presentPaymentMethods',
    'as'   => 'products.presentPaymentMethods'
]);
```

jQuery to navigatte between steps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a.nav-link').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if (!divValid($('.nav-pills li a.active').prop('hash'))) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else

            if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $(".next-step").click(function(e) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            nextTab($active);
        });

        $(".prev-step").click(function(e) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            prevTab($active);
        });

        function nextTab(elem) {
            elem.parent().next().removeClass('disabled').find('a.nav-link').click();
        }

        function prevTab(elem) {
            elem.parent().prev().find('a.nav-link').click();
        }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you store the data in php session then clear it after the payment is done in your final step?

Comment: Thanks, Im storing data in session in the storeUserInfo() method. The issue is that then in the method the user is redirected to the same payment page for this url  "store.test/product/5/a-5/payment/paymentMethods". But in this page still apears the step 1 as the default but it should appear the step 2 because the user clicked previously in the "go to step 2" button.

Comment: try adding another session name/value for step, when first step is submitted set the session to `2` then in the page check if the session is `2` hide first step and show step `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just collect all the data with js and post all at once to the server, I feel like you are going about this in a really complex way.

Alternatively, collect your data for step one, post to server redirect the user to step 2, and repeat.

e.g.

```
Route::get('step1', 'step3@PaymentController')->name('step1');
Route::post('step1store', 'step1@PaymentController')->name('step1-store');
Route::get('step2', 'step2@PaymentController')->name('step2');
Route::post('step2store', 'step2@PaymentController')->name('step2-store');
Route::get('step3', 'step3@PaymentController')->name('step3');
Route::post('step3store', 'step3@PaymentController')->name('step3-store');

public function step1store(Request $request)
{
    //process your data and store to db
    return redirect()->route('step2');
}

public function step2store(Request $request)
{
    //process your data and store to db
    return redirect()->route('step3');
}

public function step3store(Request $request)
{
    //process your data and store to db
    return redirect()->route('step4');
}
```

I'm sure you get the idea. Personally, I would go with posting all the data at once verifying each page with ajax.

Comment: Thanks, with your alternative example it seems similar to what I have in the question but do you know how to after redirect the user to step2 (in your example in the step1store() method, in the question the storeUserInfo() method) show that step2 in the page after the page is refreshed? Because as it is when the user is redirected to the same payment page after click in "go  to step 2" the step that is visible is still the step 1.

Comment: I dont have much exprience with ajax, but you are saying is collect the data with jquery for example in each step and in each step send a ajax post request? But in each step is not necessary to store in db, just in the 3 step is necessary to store in db.

Comment: Yeah that's it so lets just say in step 1 you have first_name, last_name and email. You would take that data pass it to a validator via ajax if it returns with a success then store the data with js , and proceed to next step, repeat for all the steps that collect data and on your final step, step 3 post all the validated data to the server via ajax and on success return the invoice for step 4.

Comment: Thanks, but first is necessary to pass the data to a validatior with ajax and only after store in js? It is not the opposite? first necessary to store with jQuery the data and only send to the validator with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```js
$(function(){
 $('.next_step').click(function(){
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-nexttab');
    $('.tabs').hide().removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $(tab).show().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide{
 display:none;
}
.show{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs show" id="tabs1">
Continue Here
<button type="button" data-nexttab="#tabs2" class="next_step">next</button>
</div>
<div class="tabs hide" id="tabs2">
Continue Here 2
<button type="button" data-nexttab="#tabs3" class="next_step">next</button>
</div>
<div class="tabs hide" id="tabs3">
Continue Here 3
<button type="submit" class="next_step">finish</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when the user is redirected to the same payment page after click in "go to step"  the step that is visible is still the step 1.